# Reverse 'date created' order in desktop mac

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

When I create or add new Item to my macOS Desktop, macOS arrange the new one at very beging on top right, which I wish it to add the new item after latest one in very bottom left, Is there a way for solving this issue? Any terminal command?

Comment: This is such a simple thing, really needs to be default, as the end of a list is the most intuitive place to look for a new file that was created (not at the start of the list). I use command + 3/4 a lot to take screenshots and after years the odd choice of placement of the new file still confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always fill any spaces starting top right & working back leftwards in columns. That's just how it works - opposite to Windows. If you drag items they will land where you drag, but creating new will conform to that arrangement, even if you switch off all sort/arrange options. It has to put it somewhere & that's the default pattern.

Comment: Thanks, can we think that maybe there is a software or code in Terminal for it?

Comment: I very much doubt it.